# Group duplicate records in SQL Server where some field = 0

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
| LastName | FirstName | Title                | isdefault |
+----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+
| Davolio  | Nancy     | Sales Representative | 1         |
| Fuller   | Andrew    | Vice President, Sales| 1         |
| Fuller   | Andrew    | Vice President, Sales| 0         |
| Fuller   | Andrew    | Vice President, Sales| 0         |
| Leverling| Janet     | Sales Representative | 0         |
| Leverling| Janet     | Sales Representative | 0         |
| Leverling| Janet     | Sales Representative | 0         |
```

in a SQL Server database.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    LastName, FirstName, Title, isdefault 
FROM 
    Employees
```

I wish to select equal records, where `isdefault = 0`. So my new output should be:

```
| LastName | FirstName | Title                | isdefault |
+----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+
| Leverling| Janet     | Sales Representative | 0         |
| Leverling| Janet     | Sales Representative | 0         |
| Leverling| Janet     | Sales Representative | 0         |
```

I tried to use `GROUP BY`:

```
 SELECT 
    LastName, FirstName, Def_flag 
 FROM 
    Employees 
 WHERE 
    Def_flag = 0 
 GROUP BY 
    LastName, FirstName, Def_flag
```

but the result doesn't satisfy me because the record Andrew Fuller get into the table too.

How do I need to change query?

Regards, Alexander.

Comment: And this is tagged mysql because...?

Comment: oh,i'm sorry, my fault - mssql

Comment: Is the first record not identical??

Comment: Alexander, you'll need to state your question more clearly. Tell us why Andrew Fuller should *not* be in the results, because based on your question as it reads right now, he should be.

Comment: I need to select records where last, first name and title are the same and at the same time isdefault = 0. I want to do this because it is an error(records can be identical, but field isdefault must be = 1 like Andrew Fuller) and I wish to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you think about it ? This would give you the result you're looking for.

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM Employees e1
    left join (SELECT distinct LastName, FirstName FROM Employees t WHERE isdefault = 1 ) exclude
        ON e1.FirstName = exclude.FirstName
        AND e1.LastName = exclude.LastName
WHERE (Exclude.FirstName IS NULL AND Exclude.LastName IS NULL)
```

I assume the FirstName+LastName is your key. In case you have an id, you should replace it..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, employees where all entries for Def_flag are 0?

```
select
    LastName,
    FirstName, 
    Def_flag 
from (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                LastName,FirstName
            ORDER BY
                Def_flag DESC
        ) i
        LastName,
        FirstName, 
        Def_flag 
    FROM Employees
) T
where
    i = 1 and
    Def_flag = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming isdefault is a bit, you could do this. Otherwise use sum(isdefault) = 0, although it still would work as it is. I am assuming is default can never be negative

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Title 
FROM <yourtable>
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName, Title
HAVING sum(isdefault+0) = 0
```

This will return

```
LastName   FirstName  Title
Leverling  Janet      Sales Representative
```